# Exchanging characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need to exchange the middle character in a numeric string of 15 numbers with the last number of the string.

So I get that this:

```
def string(str):  
      return str[-1:] + str[1:-1] + str[:1]  

print(string('abcd'))  
print(string('12345'))
```

RESULTS:

```
dbca
52341
```

But how can I make it so that in the initial input string, 012345678912345,

where the 7 is exchanged with the last character in the string 5?

Comment: Can we assume the length of the strings is always odd?

Comment: Yep! the length will always be odd. 15 characters.

Comment: `text[0:7]+text[-1]+text[8:-1]+text[7]` - also try to avoid variable names like `str`, since they shadow the function of the same name.

Comment: thank you so much! i didn't know to add another slice operation there! and i will definitely replace the str with some other name!

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
def last_to_mid(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s

    if len(s)%2 == 0:            
        raise ValueError('expected string of odd length')

    idx = len(s)//2
    return f'{s[:idx]}{s[-1]}{s[idx+1:-1]}{s[idx]}'
```

operating like this:

```
>>> last_to_mid('021')
'012'
>>> last_to_mid('0123x4567')
'01237456x'
>>> last_to_mid('1')
'1'
```

Assuming you have Python 3.6 or newer for [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function for this:

```
    In [178]: def swap_index_values(my_string):
     ...:     l = list(my_string)
     ...:     middleIndex = (len(l) - 1)/2 
     ...:     middle_val = l[middleIndex]
     ...:     l[middleIndex] = l[-1]
     ...:     l[-1] = middle_val
     ...:     return ''.join(l)
     ...: 

    In [179]: 

    In [179]: a
    Out[179]: '012345678912345'

    In [180]: swap_index_values(a)
    Out[180]: '012345658912347'
```

Above, you can see that middle value and last values have been exchanged.

Comment: I think you are missing the conversion to `int` for `middleIndex`, I'm getting a `TypeError` without that conversion for your code. Also, `replace_middle_index('123')` produces `'133'` so there seems to be a bug.

Comment: The OP wanted to replace the middle element from the last element. So, I guess, `123` will be changed to `133` only.

Comment: OP said "exchange", not "replace", which I interpreted as "swap". You are right though, the question lacks the expected output.

Comment: Got it. Edited my asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

In this very specific context (always the middle and last character of a string of length 15), your initial approach can be extended to:

```
text[0:7]+text[-1]+text[8:-1]+text[7]
```

Also try to avoid variable names like `str`, since they shadow the function of the same name.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you Christian. From slice 0:7 you return only 0123456 then add -1 which is 5 and add the remaining 891234 and finally you added the final bit which in this case at text[7] is 7. Its so clear to me now that I feel like a fool for not figuring it out  beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

```
s1='1243125'
s2=s1[:len(s1)//2] + s1[-1] + s1[len(s1)//2 + 1:]
print(s2)
```

'1245125'